# Android show input keyboard only when user press a button

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a PopupWindow in one Activity.
When user press on the list item in the activity, the window will popup for getting input from users.

There are some EditText in the window. And also I provided some buttons that preset some text on it, so when user press on it then it will enter to the edittext.

I can disable the softkeyboard when the window first popup. But when I change the focus on edittext (Move from one edittext to another edittext), the keyboard shown up.

I want the softkeyboard show only when user press on the "show keyboard" button in the popup window
How can I do it?

Updated:

```
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
     if (hasFocus)  {
         selectedEditText = (EditText)view;
         String text = selectedEditText.getText().toString();
         selectedEditText.setSelection(text.length());
         InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(selectedEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
     }
}
```

I tried the code above but it still showing.

Answer (score 0):

set `onFocusChangedListener()` on every editText you have and disable Keyboard Pop inside it if it has focus..

Show it only when the user Presses the button..

Comment: I updated my code, but it still showing the keyboard on focus changed, is the code doing something wrong?

Comment: I logged the result in the if body, the body part has executed. I added to test inputManager.isActive() at the end but it always return true

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple solution too; create fake focus above your EditText and you good to go.
Like this:

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
   </LinearLayout>
   <!--Your EditText-->
   <EditText
       ...
   </EditText>
```

also you can add these two line above your mentioned EditText in any VIEW, like TextView and so on.

```
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the xml and find the activity in which you want to hide keyboard
add given attribute to the Activity..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```